# Downloading Themes for GUI in windows application?

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2010, gui, visual-studio-2008, c#

Is it possible to download from the net or customize the GUI, or form of a windows application made in Visual Studio?

I have tried to make the form better to look at, but i want cool or casual look on the form

Comment: *Please* don't.

Comment: dont what? sir gravvity

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Krypton Toolkit](http://www.componentfactory.com/) for a free toolkit that will do basic "skinning" of your own winform application.

But, if you really want a next-gen UI to build your application with (MS based next-gen that is) - switch to [Windows Presentation Foundation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation).

Now if you are asking how to change the UI of somebody else's application, then that is beyond the scope of this conversation, and I will just say you can't, easily.....